# php/jquery - Only show page content when loading externally

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an index page where I'm using jquery's `.load()` function to load external page contents inside a `div`.

My 'problem' is that if the user acess the file itself, he will also see the page content, but I don't want that. I only want the page to be loaded if it's being loaded inside the index page throughout the `.load()` function.

What can I do to apply this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.load()` method is using ajax, you should be able to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`. I might create a reusable function to check.

**/functions/isAjaxRequest.php**

```
function isAjaxRequest($type = 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')
{
    return (!empty($_SERVER[$type]) && strtolower($_SERVER[$type]) == 'xmlhttprequest');
}
```

**/ajax_load_page.php**

```
<?php
# Add the function
require_once(__DIR__.'/functions/isAjaxRequest.php');
# Stop if not ajax
$isAjax = isAjaxRequest();
if(!$isAjax)
    die('Invalid Request.');
?>
<p>This is a valid request!</p>
```

Though headers can be faked by clients, the average user is not going to try and circumvent this.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much @Rasclatt

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion would be to simply load it in PHP by including it as part of `index.php`.

Second way to do it would be to use `$_SESSION`.  Set a session key from index.php and then check it in the file you're loading:

#### index.php

```html
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['activatedFromIndexPage'] = true;

?>
<div id='foo'>Your HTML here</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').load('bar.php');
  });
</script>
```

#### bar.php

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(!array_key_exists('activatedFromIndexPage',$_SESSION)) {
  // if the key is not set, you didn't get here by way of index.php
  die;
}
?>
<div>your output goes here...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @Tim Morton